# How to find null value in file using Unix cmd

Tags: text-processing, csv

```
Id, name, currency
101,aaa, 10000
102,BBB,
103,ccc, 20000
```

I know I have an empty cell currency column. How do I find it using a terminal command?

Comment: Does "null" mean "empty" or does it mean the literal string `null-(blank)` as in your question? Are the spaces in the start of the fields part of the actual data?  What is the actual output that you want given the data that you show in the question?

Comment: No any data it's empty record...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you data looks like this:

```
Id,name,currency
101,aaa,10000
102,BBB,
103,ccc,20000
```

Then you can print the lines that contain no data in the 3rd field using

```
$ awk -F , '$3 == ""' file.csv
102,BBB,
```

The `-F ,` on the command line sets the input field delimiter to a comma, so `awk` will split each line on commas into separate fields.
The condition `$3 == ""` means "field 3 is empty" (and "empty" means "doesn't even contain a space"), and if that is *true*, then the default action will be taken. The default action is to print the current line.

Would you want to also output the header line:

```
$ awk -F , 'NR == 1 || $3 == ""' file.csv
Id,name,currency
102,BBB,
```

The condition `NR == 1 || $3 == ""` means "if this is the first line, or if the 3rd field is empty".

Would you want to add the line number to each line of output, use

```
$ awk -F , 'NR == 1 || $3 == "" { print NR, $0 }' file.csv
1 Id,name,currency
3 102,BBB,
```

Here, instead of the *default* action, we trigger a block that prints the current line number (`NR`) along with the original line of text from the file (`$0`).

Comment: Hy really useful & thankful...

Answer (score 0):

`grep -n "null-(blank)" file.txt` will output every line (with line number) where "null-(blank)" occurs

To just check in the currency column you could use the following regex pattern:

```
grep -n "[^,]*,[^,]*,[ ]*null-(blank)" file.txt
```

Comment: I need to check only for the currency column

Comment: The data is empty ....how to get

Comment: Edited the answer for just searching in the third column